# GitLab CI with JS Linting

Tags: javascript, gitlab, eslint, gitlab-ci

I have 0 experience with GitLab Continuous Integration and I need to setup a job to run ESLint on .js files.

I've already read the GitLab CI and Pipeline documentations, along with some Git Hooks, but I still have no idea how to setup this, so any detailed and starting from the very beginning answer is appreciated.

Comment: First questions to form a proper answer: Do you have a runner set up, and if so, what type?

Comment: No, I don't @StefanvanGastel.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First you need to setup your CI and have some runners available so they can run your continuous integration jobs. The easiest way for this is to use `gitlab-ci-multi-runner` (project is [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner) along with [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/)) along with the docker executor that will run your CI jobs in docker containers. Once you have configured some runners, [add](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/runners/#creating-and-registering-a-runner) them to your Gitlab project so they're available to run jobs.

Once that's taken care of, you need to add a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to your project. This file is used to describe the jobs that need to run during continuous integration etc. Here is an example (assuming you install `eslint` using `npm`)

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - lint

eslint:
  stage: lint
  script:
    # Install ESLint in this docker container
    - npm install -g eslint
    # Configure ESLint (will read your .eslintrc file)
    - eslint --init
    # Run ESLint
    - eslint <your_js_file>
```

Add your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, commit and push the changes. The CI pipeline should start and run the above steps.

Comment: If checking stuff that require other linters or validators, you can also use an   ubuntu image and then install npm like so (sorry, no formatting in comments):

    image: ubuntu:artful

    before_script:

      - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq npm

Comment: In addition to this you need to know, you will need a Gitlab CI Runner (which is a server where CI Runner can be installed & ran by Gitlab)

Comment: how to run eslint on all the files?

Comment: `eslint --init` does not read the eslintrc - it creates it in an interactive wizard, this should not be part of the pipeline

Comment: The answer is fine but <your js file> is not useful when you are working with hundreds of files. Does anyone have a better solution for this?

Comment: `eslint .` will run eslint on all files in the current directory, recursively.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to have comments to your PRs here is an example with eslint and [pronto](https://github.com/prontolabs/pronto). (we have ruby app so we check ruby code style too )

```
image: 'circleci/ruby:2.5.1-node-browsers'

codestyle:
  script:
  - sudo apt -y install cmake
  # install eslint dependencies
  - sudo npm install -g eslint
  - sudo npm install -g eslint-plugin-babel
  - sudo npm install -g eslint-plugin-react
  - sudo npm install -g eslint-plugin-import
  - sudo npm install -g babel-eslint
  - sudo npm install -g eslint-config-airbnb
  - sudo npm install -g eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y
  # install pronto runners
  - gem install pronto --no-ri
  - gem install pronto-rubocop --no-ri
  - gem install rubocop-rspec --no-ri
  - gem install pronto-eslint_npm --no-ri
  # run linters
  - vendor/ruby/bin/pronto run -f gitlab -c origin/dev --exit-code
```

You can also run linters separately:

`- vendor/ruby/bin/pronto run -r eslint_npm -f gitlab -c origin/dev --exit-code`

This piece `-f gitlab -c origin/dev` tells linters to check only changed lines of code.

Also if you use `pronto-eslint_npm` and want to check files in specific folder add

`.pronto_eslint_npm.yml` that will contain needed regex. (in my case it has next line)

```
files_to_lint: app\/frontend\/\S*(\.js|\.es6|\.jsx)$
```