# GitLab CI with ESLint --init Failing on a Prompt for Input

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, eslint

I have followed the [instructions in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43318794/3112803) for setting up ESLint in GitLab CI.  It is failing because ESLint during the init stops to ask a question...

```
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ npm install -g eslint
/usr/local/bin/eslint -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js
+ eslint@5.16.0
added 117 packages from 70 contributors in 7.16s
$ eslint --init
? How would you like to use ESLint? (Use arrow keys)
  To check syntax only 
❯ To check syntax and find problems 
  To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I do have a `.eslintrc` file present in the root of my repository.  How do I get around this prompt/questions causing my pipeline to fail?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an .eslintrc file in the root of your repository, you don't need to set it again. I followed the same set of instructions and was vexed by this issue too until I commented the `--init` line out. Here's my ESLint task, for reference:

```
eslint:
  <<: *exclude_tags
  stage: lint
  image: node
  tags:
    - web
  before_script:
    - call npm i -g eslint-cli
    - call npm i eslint --save-dev
    - call npm i @typescript-eslint/parser --save-dev
    - call npm i @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin --save-dev
    - call npm i eslint-plugin-security --save-dev
  script:
    - node node_modules\eslint\bin\eslint.js --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src/
  allow_failure: true
```